# copper spiral birth control not toxic?

Tags: human-biology

I Always thought that copper was toxic to the human body.
So how can it be safe to place a copper object (birth control spiral) into a uterus for a duration of 5 years?

Comment: It is toxic enough to disrupt reproduction which is relatively sensitive, but not enough to kill anyone.  Still there are side effects that show up often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copper is toxic, however from a copper device insufficient levels enter the bloodstream to cause any harm. The released copper is however toxic to sperm. Nevertheless at the site of insertion, they can cause inflammation (especially in the first 21 days and during menstruation) and thus they also recruit white blood cells and the increase in levels of prostaglandins. However, this isn't that common.